# Origin of the word "pinkendindies"

Tags: etymology

I was wondering if anyone has ever come across the term “pink-in-dindies,” which I came across in a Dublin newspaper from Dec. 1780 which records that “*ruffians distinguished by the appellation of Pink-in-dindies- without provocation- threw a decently dressed man into the river over a wall at Inn’s Quay.*"

There's nothing online or in the OED that's helped - although the OED does record the word 'pinkeen' which is apparently Anglo-Irish for a little minnow, or, figuratively a very diminutive or insignificant person. The first citation is from 1831.

Could pinkindindies be a (half humorous?) approximation to "picaninnies" - first OED record of which is mid 18th c. ??

Any info gratefully received.

Comment: It is in [Brewer's Dictionary of Irish Phrase & Fable](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780199916191.001.0001/acref-9780199916191-e-4262) - but paywalled

Comment: It's a slang usage from two-and-a-half centuries ago, that obviously has no currency today. But it's easy to find the etymology from several online sources, so why does it need to be asked about here?

Comment: It could easily be a local pronunciation of _pickanniny_, a derogatory term for black and mixed-race people, common wherever the slave trade was practiced (which included all Anglophone countries in 1780).

Comment: Try searching 'Pink-in-dindies'

Answer (score 10):

[Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/mxhjhtq) suggests it is a term of Irish origin which dates back to the 18th century. There is apparently no derivation from [picaninny](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pickaninny)

> ***Pinkindindies*** n.
> also pinking-dindees
> [lit. ‘a turkey-cock given to pinking with a rapier’]

> (Irish) a gang of dissolute, rich young men who cut off the bottom few inches of their scabbards and prod or ‘pink’ with their exposed sword point those whom they encounter and with whom they can start an argument.

> - 1778    [Ire]   Dublin Eve. Post 3 Nov. 3/3: Our active Chief Magistrate has declared war against pinkindindies, gamblers, sabbath breakers [etc].
> - 1783    [Ire]   Hibernian Jrnl (Dublin) 22 Dec. 4/4: A general Meeting of the antient [...] Society of noct-ambulants, vulgarly called Pick-pockets, Gamblers, Bullies, Pinken-dindies, Foot-pads, and Draggled-drabs .

[Mentalfloss.com](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/651787/historic-gang-name-origins) provides a few more details on the origin of the term ***pinkindindies:***

> The Pinkindindies or “Pinking Dindies” were an 18th-century gang of young men from wealthy or aristocratic backgrounds that robbed and terrorized Dubliners for sport or, sometimes, for money.
>
> The author David Ryan details the origin of their unusual appellation:
> It derives from the slang verb to pink, which, according to A
> Classical Dictionary of the Vulgar Tongue (1785), means “to stab or
> wound with a small sword, probably derived from the holes formerly cut
> in both men and women’s clothes, called pinking,” and dindies, a
> variation of “dandies.”

Comment: The "turkey-cock" suggested by Green's would be suggestive of the French *dinde* from *coq d'inde*, which could conflict with *dandy* as a source